# How do I access the server log which have timestamp?

Tags: shell-script

I have server logs with the name :

server.log.2020-12-01
server.log.2020-12-02
server.log.2020-12-03
server.log.2020-12-02

I want to check that it is updates daily and print the last few lines as the output if the logs exists.

I tried doing it this way

```
Present_log=find  /home/username/example_server_logs/server.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
echo "tail -2 /home/username/example_server_logs/server.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d) | grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

But this hasnt helped

Comment: Just found you created a duplicate of your own question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622857/how-do-i-access-the-server-log-which-have-timestamp You should have edited it rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if the server.log is updated everyday?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622702/how-do-i-check-if-the-server-log-is-updated-everyday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you may do this :

```
# save the current logfile name in a variable once for all
Present_log="/home/username/example_server_logs/server.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"

if [ -f "$Present_log" ]; then # checking whether today's logfile exists
    # dealing with today's logfile
    # you may add further processing of the logfile here if required
    tail -2 "$Present_log"
else
    echo 'no logfile found'
fi
```

- you can't do things like `myVariable=find...`. If you want to retrieve the result of a command into a variable, you'll have to use the `$(...)` operator : `myVariable=$(find...)`
- you don't need `find` since you already know the full path + file name
- more about the [**[ -f ...]** operator](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)
- what you're trying to achieve with the `echo "tail ..."` line is unclear. `tail`, `grep` and others actually output text (depending on their input + parameters, of course) and don't need `echo` to display a result. If nothing is displayed, it generally means nothing was found.